# Command to list connected devices on BlackBerry WebWorks

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-webworks

I remember using a command from within the BlackBerry WebWorks SDK which would list all the devices connected(including BB simulators) as well as the IP address of the devices.

What is the command-line/terminal command to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about this a few days I've come to the realization that I made a mistake. While learning Webworks and the Android SDK at the same time I seem to have confused the android command..

```
adb devices
```

..with BlackBerry. After searching for a few days I'm 90% sure there is no equivalent command on BlackBerry Webworks SDK.

***THERE IS NO COMMAND TO LIST CONNECTED DEVICES, AT THIS TIME.***